# Flexbox layout overflowing window

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, overflow

Created a simple flexbox layout with 2 rows, 1 header row, 1 main content, with second row containing 2 cols, 1 of which I wanted to stretch 100% to height of window (so it could have scrollable items) and the 2nd col sat to the right for content (again scrollable). I've set `html, body` to:

`height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;`

to help achieve the layout.

Everything seems fine apart from the layout pushes off the bottom of the window to the height of the header. If I remove the header no content is pushed out of view.

Is it possible to keep the header row and make the second row stay within the window?

[jsFiddle to try and illustrate the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/7856241/owbacrg8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex items by default have a minimum height/width equal to content, In other words a flex item cannot be smaller than it's content.

To override that behaviour use `min-height:0;` to `.sectionRow2`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.sectionRow1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.sectionRow2 {
  min-height: 0;
  /* New */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.sectionRow2Col1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: silver;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sectionRow2Col2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.menuitems {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.menufoot {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 40px;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.headerlogo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <header class="sectionRow1">
    <div class="headerlogo">
      <a href="#">Header</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="sectionRow2">
    <nav class="sectionRow2Col1">
      <div class="menuitems">
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="menufoot">Footer</div>
    </nav>

    <section class="sectionRow2Col2">
      <div class="content">
        Content..
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> Content..
      </div>
    </section>

  </section>

</div>
```